# Android mediarouter for streaming sdcard videos to PC

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, multimedia

Can android MediaRouter (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NGB10uN6OI) use for streaming sdcard videos to PC or other device as RTSP or TCP stream? So that can be played using vlc or other player?